# How do I upgrade mysql 5.5.24 to 5.5.27 on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, mysql

I've bee running around for about 1 1/2 hours now trying to figure out how to do an upgrade. Can anyone direct me to a tutorial on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the most recent mysql version in the official repositories is [5.5.24](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-5.5/). Even Ubuntu 12.10, which is in the testing phase, only has 5.5.25.

If you want to upgrade to 5.5.27, you have two options, neither of which will probably successfully "upgrade" your existing installation, may break future official Ubuntu mysql updates, and may or may not work:

- Install the 5.5.27 deb packages (for Debian) from [the official website.](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/)
- Build 5.5.27 from source (also available at the MySQL website).

Comment: Thanks! That explains why all the troubles I've been having.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a script to assist you in upgrading to the latest release of MySQL.
Please see my post here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1933991